# touch switch time problem

Tags: arduino, switches, timer, 555

I was looking for a way to make a touch touch switch and i found this circuit on the internet  but the problem is , it goes off automatically after few seconds
is there any way that i can control it manually ?
thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The inputs need pull up and pull down resistors of 1M or more. Pin 2 gets a resistor connected to V+; pin 6 one connected to V-. I am assuming your finger bridges the touch plate.